# Making HTTP Requests in Qt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, libcurl, curlpp, qtnetwork

I'm new to **Qt**. I installed Qt for VS2008 and integrated with my **VS2010**. I just want to know how to make HTTP requests. I've read about **QtNetwork** but QtHttp is obselete.

I also know about **libcurl** and **curlpp**, but I have problems installing it, and making it work with Qt.

What do you recommend, **QtNetwork** or **curlpp**? If **QtNetwork**, can you please give me a sample function or piece of code (and what class to use). If **curlpp(libcurl)**, can you please point me to somewhere where I can find the steps to install it for **Qt** (or kindly explain)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*libcurl* and *curlpp* are great libraries, but using them adds a dependency to your project that probably you can avoid.

Recent versions of Qt recommend to use [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to make network requests (included http requests) and receive replies.

The simplest possible way to download a file is:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")));
```

When the `replyFinished` slot is called, the [`QNetworkReply`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkreply.html) object that it takes as parameter will contain the downloaded data as well as meta-data (headers, etc.).

A more complete example can be found in the Qt examples, you can [read here its source code](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/network-http.html).

Answer (score 5):

Giuseppe is right, you don't need to use *libcurl*, *curlpp* and similar libraries.
There is no need for that, Qt has a simple and working class on it own.

Keep in mind that the standard way of sending request and retrieving reply is asynchronous.
You always have to connect the manager finished(QNetworkReply*) signal to a slot.

If you send multiple requests and don't want to add a slot for each reply, you can always run an event loop, and connect the managers signal to event loops quit() slot.

Something like this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QEventLoop *eventLoop = new QEventLoop();
QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), eventLoop, SLOT(quit());

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com")));
eventLoop->exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);

QByteArray replyData = reply->readAll();
... //do what you want with the data your receive from reply
```

Btw. don't know what are you doing. But if its a mobile app, I would recommend you switch from VS to QtCreator IDE. It has a nice simulator and a complete toolchain for mobile device testing.